# rvm: command not found (Fedora 12)

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, fedora

After I installed rvm using the following command in my Fedora 12 system:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable –ruby
```

When I want to use rvm, it says

rvm: command not found

I want to use rvm for: `rvm install 1.9.3`

What is the solution.

Comment: Check your path, check your rvm directory first. Has it really installed, or is it in the path?

Comment: there is no rvm directory. I tried with: find / -name 'rvm' -type d      but there is nothing. But in my mac os i can find rvm with the same command

Comment: Hmm, have you tried `.rvm`? Usually it is installed at `~/.rvm` or `/usr/local/rvm`

Comment: Yes i checked. its not there. it seems that rvm is not installed. I tried \curl -L https://get.rvm.io many times. but its not working. But its strange. Few days ago, i installed rvm in a fedora based system with the same command.....what is wrong??

Comment: Hard to say. So does `curl` works fine? The installation shell script is downloaded OK?

Comment: I am not sure but it downloads sth: i get the following msg: Usage

  rvm-installer [options] [action]  and some other info thats all. it does not say rvm installed sucessfully

Comment: Have you tried reload your shell? Like logout and login again.

Comment: where did you get this command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command uses an en-dash ('–',  U+2013):

> \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable –ruby

but the installation instructions at https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ use a double ASCII dash, '--':

> \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby